# UserControl controls and values available in Locals window, but not accessible in the code

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a silly problem - I am handling an event (Selected Tab Changed) of a tab control and I want to set the window title to be indentical as tab header.
Tab Header is a user control which contains three text blocks.

The code:

```
TabItem item = tabCtrl.SelectedItem as TabItem;
if (item.Header is TabHeader)
{
   // the topTextBlock is not visible
   // string topText = (item.Header as TabHeader).topTextBlock.Text;
}
```

The problem is that when I hover over the item.Header, or go to the Locals window, the tooltip shows the required textblocks and I can see their text. So how do I access them from the code?

`(item.Header as TabHeader)` gives access to a bunch of various properties and methods (width, height, cliptobounds, contextMenu etc).

Cheers!

Comment: [Try using the `FindName` method.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

Comment: Can't you just have a `HeaderText` property in your TabHeader control and bind the Window Title like `Title="{Binding SelectedItem.Header.HeaderText, ElementName=tabCtrl}"`?

Comment: @MikeEason Thanks Mike, that did the trick!
Any idea why was it not available?

Comment: @Bartosz Because the field `topTextBlock` is generated private in class TabControl. You can modify that, but you shouldn't. Accessing the control that way is also not the right way to do. You should instead expose a public property in your TabHeader control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `topTextBlock` (which is generated from `x:Name="topTextBlock"` in XAML) is private by default. You could change it to be generated public, but you shouldn't do that. You should also avoid to lookup the field by `FindName`.

Expose a public property instead

```
public partial class TabHeader : UserControl
{
    public string TopText
    {
        get { return topTextBlock.Text; }
    }

    ...
}
```

and use it either in code behind

```
var topText = ((TabHeader)item.Header).TopText;
```

or in a binding

```
Title="{Binding SelectedItem.Header.TopText, ElementName=tabCtrl}"
```

Comment: Hi Clemens - your solution with a property works great, thanks. Out of curiosity I tried setting the `x:FieldModifier="public" ` on the text block, but it didn't appear either.

Comment: Exactly that works for me. Maybe you have to rebuild?

Comment: Maybe - not important, as you say this is not the proper way. I am however struggling to set the databining in code to the WindowTitle. `this.Title` does not have the `SetBinding()` method. I cannot specify this in XAML, because the tab controls contains various tab header types - and I only want the binding to be for a specific type of header.

Comment: Assumed that `this` is the Window instance, you would write `this.SetBinding(Window.TitleProperty, new Binding(...))`, or shorter `SetBinding(TitleProperty, new Binding(...))`.